# sql server store comparison operators in database and use in case statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, comparison-operators

I have a requirement to store the comparison operator symbols in sql database and then., use these comparison ooperators incase statements on other columns to render result. Can I know how can I get the comparison operatopr value in the case statement and then use them in case..

Something like .. 
[sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/134iy.png)

Now, I need to apply the operator from symbol column on other columns and check if condition is satisfied , accordingly display the result. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function like this, which supports >,>=,<,<= and = operators:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func_Generic_Compare 
(

    @Param1 float,
    @Param2 float,
    @operator varchar(2)

)
RETURNS nvarchar(5)
AS
BEGIN

if @operator = '>' or @operator = '>='
   if @Param1 > @Param2 
       return 'True'

if @operator = '<' or @operator = '<='
   if @Param1 < @Param2 
       return 'True'

if @operator = '=' or @operator = '<=' or @operator = '>='
   if @Param1 = @Param2 
       return 'True'

RETURN 'False'

END
```

And then use `select dbo.func_Generic_Compare (col1,col2,operator) as Result from table`

Using a function like this will have a serious performance impact (It's processed 'row by agonising row'!)  but will be fine for small-ish datasets.

Another option would be a nested case statement.  for clarity you could do it in two steps

```
Select col1, col2, operator,
case when operator='>' then 
    greater 
else 
    case when operator='<' then 
        less 
    else 
        equal 
    end 
end as result 

from

(Select 
     col1, 
     col2,
     operator, 
     col1>col2 as greater, 
     col1<col2 as less, 
     col1=col2 as equal
from 
compare) as PreCalculated
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6df0d/1)

Another option would be

```
Select Col1, Col2, Col1>Col2  as Results
from Table
where operator = '>'
union all

Select Col1, Col2, Col1<Col2 
from Table
where operator = '<'
union all

Select Col1, Col2, Col1<Col2 
from Table
where operator = '='
```

Comment: I need to perform that operator comparison on both the columns like, case when col1 + operator +col2 then 'True' else 'False' end, so if the condition satisfies, my result will be true, else false.. I have many columns, I need a generic code..

Comment: Your code works.. But I have 12 sets of such columns.. Its tedious to write the same for 12 sets.. let me see how can I make this generic to all ..

Comment: This does not appear to be valid SQL for SQL Server.  Specifically comparison expressions like `col1>col4` are *not* valid column expressions.

Comment: "it's tedious" .. that's why you get the big bucks my friend! ... To make it SQL-Server friendly, replace col1>col2 with a case when col1>col2 then true etc.  If some friendly person doesn't edit it i'll do it when i'm finished work!  Maybe you could do it with dynamic SQL in a UDF.

Comment: @JeffUk.. haha, I said it&#39;s tedious, hence I&#39;ll try for s generic code.. At the end we all want to write less complex code.. Right now I have stored the &#39;col1&#39;+operator+&#39;col2&#39; in a resultant column, I need to see if I can get the output result during runtime for it... UDF is what I&#39;m also thinking of.. Let me try today.. :)

Comment: Updated with UDF, unfortunately you can't do dynamic SQL inside a function